# Codeigniter : route doesn't work when calling php script through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, routes

I have a JS file which calls a php script using a relative path. The path used has a matching route in **route.php**.

The issue is that the route doesn't seem to be correctly applied when the php script is called from the JS file. 
More precisely, in the php file, the parameters $1 and $2 of the function do not contain the expected values (example below).

However, when using the url directly in the browser, the parameter $1 has the correct value.

**route.php**

```
$route['ajax/quizz/(:any)'] = 'test/ajax/$1';
```

**JS file**

```
var path        = 'ajax/quizz/load_items';  //path used for the AJAX query
```

**Test.php**

```
public function ajax($elt,$elt2 = "arg2"){

    switch($elt){
        case 'quizz' :
            echo "Shouldn't come here. Argument should be 'load_items': $1 $2";
            //$this->ajax_quizz();
            break;

        case 'load_items'   :
            $this->load_items($this->input->post(null,true));
            break;

        case 'add_stats'    :
            $this->add_stats($this->input->post(null,true),$_SESSION['id']);
            break;

        default :
            echo 'Unknown ajax function '.$elt;
    }
}
```

**Expected behaviour**

When the AJAX query is performed, the path specified (*ajax/quizz/load_items*) should match the route *ajax/quizz/(:any)* and the resulting path should be *test/ajax/load_items*.

As a consequence, we expect the controller **test** to be called, and function **ajax** to be executed, with argument $1 = **load_items**.

**Actual behaviour**

When called through AJAX, from the JS file, the path **ajax/quizz/load_items** has the following effect :

- The controller *test* is called
- The function *ajax* is executed
- Argument $1 = quizz (expected : **load_items**)
- Argument $2 = load_items

**Direct access through the browser**

When using this same path (http://localhost/codeigniter/ajax/quizz/load_items) directly in the browser, i get the expected behaviour :

- The controller *test* is called
- The function *ajax* is executed
- Argument $1 = load_items

Do you see where my issue might come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your js ajax path full.Instead of using `ajax/quizz/load_items` use

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/ajax/quizz/load_items.
```

Comment: Hello Shaiful. First, thank you for your answer. It does work when i put the full URL, as you suggested. However, it is very important for me to keep a relative path, as later, it will not be "localhost/codeigniter/ajax/quizz/load_items, but something like www.my-website/ajax/quizz/load_items. So i really need to keep a relative path.

Comment: You can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420759/codeigniter-base-url-not-working-properly-for-ajax how you can make initial parts dynamically

Comment: Hello Shaiful. Thanks a lot. Link you provided corrected my issue.